# Function scan causing huge number of buffers hit and slower query performance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, plpgsql

I'm trying to diagnose some problematic performance issues for a Postgres query that leverages a plpgsql function.

The exact same query varying only across tenant ids is 100 times slower for Tenant A versus Tenant B. Interestingly, Tenant A has significantly less data than Tenant B but still takes two orders of magnitude longer to complete. The query plan and cost looks the same across both tenants but the number of buffers read is also 100 times more:

Tenant A `(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Aggregate  (cost=42.68..42.69 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=9947.178..9947.179 rows=1 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=8412371
```

Tenant B `(ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`:

```
Aggregate  (cost=42.68..42.69 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=149.142..149.143 rows=1 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=83373
```

Narrowing things down further I can isolate the problematic step in the query plan:

```
  ->  Function Scan on a_plgpsql_function  (cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=52) (actual time=3169.867..3169.868 rows=1 loops=3)
        Buffers: shared hit=8412369
```

The weird thing is that if I extract the function body (its a pretty straight forward parameterized `RETURN QUERY`) and try to replicate the problem without the function being a part of the picture so that I can get more details about the query plan I no longer see the performance issue popping up.

Another interesting bit of context is that I took a complete pg_dump of the database from our RDS cluster and loaded it into a local Postgres instance and the performance issue disappears and I see similar performance for both Tenant A and Tenant B.

I'm a bit outside my depth at this point and am not sure if I should start looking into manually kicking off some `VACUUM` operations or if I should look into running `CLUSTER` on some of the tables that are touched as part of the query. We do have some composite indices that typically incorporate the Tenant Id.

Any thoughts or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Running VACUUM ANALYZE on the relevant tables is usually a good idea before you spend much time digging into something. The problem might go away, and if it doesn't at least you know you have current stats for the next step.. Can you use auto_explain with log_nested_statements, log_buffers, log_analyze, and log_timing all set to true to capture the culprit in the act?

Answer (score 2):

Attention: the execution of query from `RETURN QUERY` can be different, than when you run query directly. Postgres engine can use generic plan instead custom plan, and the query can be slow.

You can try to use `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` statement instead. This statement forces custom plan always (on second hand, there is overhead with replanning).

Second note: your function returns one row. If this is typical for your function, you should to decrease the function's attribute `ROWS` (an default is 1000).

And last note: I don't like functions that are just envelope of one query. Usually this is anti-pattern. The plpgsql function is black box for optimization (when function is used in some complex query). So better is using an views (if they are possible).